# Manipulate React Render Properties

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component that is rendering data via the react-multi-select-component.  I need to change the way the data renders. The library has a property - ItemRenderer but I'm not sure how to manipulate the properties. For example:

Current data render:

- 123 Item Red
- 124 Item Blue
- 204 Item Green

Desired data render:

- Item Red (125)
- Item Blue (124)
- Item Green (204)

The actual UI code is like:

```
return (
<div>
   <MultiSelect
     options={dataListOptions}
     value = {selectedListOptions}
     onChange = {setSelectedOptions}
</div>
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manipulate the label of each item by using `ItemRenderer`. See below:

```
export default function App() {
  const options = [
    { label: "Grapes ", value: "grapes" },
    { label: "Mango ", value: "mango" },
    { label: "Strawberry ", value: "strawberry", disabled: true }
  ];
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Select Fruits</h1>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(selected)}</pre>
      <MultiSelect
        options={options}
        value={selected}
        onChange={setSelected}
        labelledBy={"Select"}
        ItemRenderer={data => data.option.label + " CHANGED"}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

It will render the option like this:

- Grapes  CHANGED
- Mango  CHANGED
- Strawberry  CHANGED

In your case, since `ItemRenderer` props accepts a function, you just have to modify it whatever you like.