# Add div component to react-multi-select

Tags: reactjs

I want to render a Card Item for each dropdown item in my react-multi-select component.
I know there is a way to change the label using the item renderer as shown in [Manipulate React Render Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62697468/manipulate-react-render-properties) but is there a way to render a more complicated UI that consists of images and divs?

This is my current code:

```
<Multiselect
    defaultMenuIsOpen
    placeholder=""
    {...field}
    inputRef={ref}
    displayValue="name"
    onSelect={(selected, item) => {
        setValue('test', selected)
        }}
        onRemove={(selected, item) => {
            setValue('test', selected)
       }}
       options={[
           { value: 'chocolate', name: 'Chocolate', id: 1 },
           { value: 'strawberry', name: 'Strawberry', id: 2 },
           { value: 'vanilla', name: 'Vanilla', id: 3 },
      ]}
/>
```

The code above gives me a UI of [image: this]

The data that I want to add in is as below:

```
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: 'Test1',
    supply: 1,
    owners: 5, 
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: 'Test2',
    supply: 10,
    owners: 50, 
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: 'Test3',
    supply: 100,
    owners: 500. 
  },
]
```

Comment: Hi, There are multiple values in your data object, How do you want to display that data in multi-select? Post an image of the dropdown you wish to implement with your  data, so we can help.

Comment: @shehanpathirathna I have added a diagram of how I would like to implement it, does it help?

Comment: I found a link that resolves your problem. Article in that link shows "How to add a checkbox to the list?". In the same way, you can add your divs and images to the Multi-Select options. Here's the link https://medium.com/geekculture/creating-multi-select-dropdown-with-checkbox-in-react-792ff2464ef3